# How to insert, update and delete records of a DataGridView to DataBase via BindingNavigator

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-binding, datagridview

I have a `Student` table and a bunch of other tables in my database called `University` and I used Entity Framework to connect to it in my winforms application.
[image: My Entity Framework model]

I created a `DataSource` from the `Student` table inside my Entity Framework model.
[image: My Data Source]

then I dragged the `DataSource` on to my form.(See the pic below)
I know how to populate the records of the `student` table (here is just one record in my DB) into the `DataGridView`, with no problem using this piece of code:

```
//An instance of my EFModel
    Oublic UniversityEntities UE = new UniversityEntities();
 private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        studentBindingSource.DataSource = UE.Students.ToList();
    }
```

[image: My Form]

But I want to use `BindingNavigator` to insert/update/delete records from/to the database and I don't khow how it's possible, considering that I use Entity Framework.

For example,I tried this to save changes after editing a row, but it didn't work:

```
 private void studentBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UE.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old thread but I faced the same problem with no answer here.

this line is breaking DataSource's connection to context:

```
studentBindingSource.DataSource = UE.Students.ToList();
```

changed it to:

```
studentBindingSource.DataSource = UE.Students;
```

but it throws an exception, so I just bind it to local data:

```
studentBindingSource.DataSource = UE.Students.Local;
```

Also you need to make sure local data has filled before binding.

Answer (score 0):

Please define "it didn't work". Is the data at least getting pushed to the underlying entity ?

I remember there was some issue with those "light weight" toolbar buttons caused by the fact that they don't cause a loss of focus, thus there's no validation happening on the datagrid.

Just before your call to UE.SaveChanges(), try forcing validation by doing:

```
this.Validate();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I meant nothing had been updated or deleted inside the DataBase.
Later, I found out about the issue with the "focus" thing and I coped with that. now updating a row works just fine but still, I cant insert a new row or delete any.