# Entity framework can update data but cannot insert new row

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I have created simple model with two related tables.

When i drag Customer as details or as dataGridView can update details using saveChanges but cannot insert new row after clicking bindingnavigator add new button and then saving changes.

Do I need code that will handle adding/updating or this is automatically generated ?

Comment: Show your xaml code. Is this WPF? or Winform

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858367/how-to-insert-update-and-delete-records-of-a-datagridview-to-database-via-bindi/37478273