# DataGridView connected to DataBase

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to connect DataGridView /w DB and everything goes well except of savin' the data from the GridView in the DB.

The TableAdapter, DataSet and BindingSource connection is ok, from my POV.

After this code run off, the table data isn't updates.

```
private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        faultsTableTableAdapter.Update(faultsTableDataSet.FaultsTable);
        MessageBox.Show("Succesfully saved!", "Message",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        faultsTableDataSet.FaultsTable.RejectChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Is your "saveBtn" a "real" Button, or one of those buttons that get added to the BindingNavigator? The second one causes issues because it doesn't "steal" focus from your last edited control, and thus the method that pushes the data to the datasource is not called. Forgive me, this has been many years ago that I ran into this. I probably have a post here somewhere.

Comment: If you are using the Binding Navigator's buttons, then look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20860744/172769

Comment: Yes, it's a "real" button the client suppose to click on after add some rows to the DataGridView table

Comment: I find the solution, maybe it will help someone with such problem: There are 2 copies of the database: 1 in the application folder and 1 in the bin\debug folder. At design time the database in the app folder is used while at run time the other one. By default in the solution explorer the database is set to COPY ALWAYS to the bin\debug folder which means that the database is alwys overwritten by the one in the application folder. Solution: I change this property to "COPY IF NEWER" and now it's works.